# MinGW linker can't find MPICH2 libraries

Tags: linker, g++, mingw

MPICH2 is installed in C:\Program Files\MPICH2. There are two subdirectories (of interest), `\include` which contains .h files, and `\lib` which contains .lib files.

The readme that comes with MPICH2 has the following instructions:

1. create a makefile
2. add `–I...mpich2\include`
3. add `–L...mpich2\lib`
4. add `–lmpi`
5. add the rules for your source files
6. compile

Since there are no other rules in my project, I don't create a makefile, I just go to the command line and try compiling like this:

```
g++ -I"C:\Program Files\MPICH2\include" main.cpp -L"C:\Program Files\MPICH2\lib" -lmpi
```

This gives me a fistful of `undefined reference` errors on every single MPI symbol in the code. I spent hours trying to fix it, juggling `-I`, `-L` and `-l` switches around, shuffling the order of the parameters, even copied all the .lib files into the same directory as my source, but nothing seems to work.

What kind of voodoo is needed to get this thing to link?

---

EDIT: I think I found the problem: here's an excerpt of the linker's output in verbose mode (adding `-Wl,--verbose` to the compile command):

```
attempt to open C:\Program Files\MPICH2\lib/libmingwex.dll.a failed
attempt to open C:\Program Files\MPICH2\lib/mingwex.dll.a failed
attempt to open C:\Program Files\MPICH2\lib/libmingwex.a failed
attempt to open C:\Program Files\MPICH2\lib/mingwex.lib failed
attempt to open C:\Program Files\MPICH2\lib/libmingwex.dll failed
attempt to open C:\Program Files\MPICH2\lib/mingwex.dll failed
attempt to open C:\Program Files\MPICH2\lib\libmingwex.a failed
```

Apparently, the linker adds a `/` instead of a `\` to the directory names I supply it with (except when looking for the `lib___.a` format for some reason), which is obviously not a valid path. Is there any way to tell the linker to use backslashes instead of slashes?

This also caught my eye:

```
attempt to open /mingw/lib/libmingwex.a succeeded
```

So I tried compiling like this:

```
g++ -I"/Program Files/MPICH2/include" -L"/Program Files/MPICH2/lib" objManager.cpp ongom.cpp io.cpp main.cpp -lmpi -lcxx
```

But I still get the same `undefined reference` errors.

Comment: mind to post the compiler / linker log?

Comment: There's really not much to see, it's just dozens of lines like this: `C:\Users\Bansaghi\AppData\Local\Temp/ccIF61Uc.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x1615): undefined reference to 'MPI_Comm_rank'`

Answer (score 3):

GCC **is able** to find your library. Otherwise it would report: `cannot find -lmpi`.

Somehow it happens that **the routines cannot be found** in that library. I managed to compile an example with this syntax:

```
g++ -I../include cpilog.c ../lib/mpi.lib ../lib/mpe.lib
```

I did that inside msys though. And my directory does not contain spaces.

After removing `libmpi.a` file, this also works:

```
g++ -I../include -L../lib cpilog.c -lmpi -lmpe
```

Answer (score 1):

try adding `-lmpicxx` (the lib for the c++ bindings), and make sure the `-l...` come *after* the cpp source file *. this works for me:

```
g++ -Iinclude -Llib test/cxxpi.cpp -lmpicxx -lmpi
```

EDIT: re: "undefined reference to 'MPI_Comm_rank'": could it be that your are mixing up / using c and / instead of c++? `MPI_Comm_rank` [seems to be](http://www.lam-mpi.org/tutorials/bindings/MPI_COMM_RANK.php) the c binding - the c++ binding would be `MPI::Comm::Get_rank()`. maybe try compiling your program as c, or, if you want to use c++, using the proper bindings (see `cxxpi.cpp` in the examples dir)?

* http://newsgroups.derkeiler.com/Archive/Comp/comp.parallel.mpi/2006-08/msg00036.html

Comment: Still getting the same `undefined reference` errors, even if I add every library and put all the parameters exactly the same order as you wrote.

Comment: did you read my edit re: c vs. c++ bindings? also, try using forward slashes, relative paths, and have no spaces in path names. eg. put your sources into "C:\Program Files\MPICH2\sc" and use -I../include -L../lib etc. in the end, it is working for me ...

Comment: oh, and by the way: the linker looks for libmpi.a and (if it's c++) libmpicxx.a - that's why the -lmpicxx -lmpi.

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar problem resulting from linking 32-bit object files with 64-bit MPICH library. Linking with 32-bit libmpi.a solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with mingw: for those library files with a .lib ending, I had to put the name of the library without the ending (e.g. -llibboost_system-mgw34-mt when the filename is libbboost_system-mgw34-mt.lib). For library files with a .a ending, I had to put the name of the library excluding the starting "lib" and the trailing .a (e.g. -lws2_32 for libws2_32.a).

So in your case - try -llibmpi (or whatever your file is called without the .lib ending), perhaps it's the same issue.

---

from: http://www.mingw.org/node/98/revisions/358/view

Note: some paths were printed with “/” as the path separator while some other was printed with “\” as the path separator. I've substitued all with “/” as MinGW GCC accept both.

So I would not put too much time into finding a way to correct the path seperator. Is your library compiled for mingw?

perhaps: http://www.mingw.org/wiki/LibraryPathHOWTO helps you a bit further.

Comment: Apparently the linker tries a variety of formats, but creates the wrong paths: see my edit in the question.

Comment: can you please tell the name of the mpi-libarary file? is it libmpi.a or libmpi.lib? This is important since if you want to link to the libmpi.lib file, you need -llibmpi instead of -lmpi

Comment: The files have no `lib` prefix, and an extension of `.lib`. e.g. `mpi.lib` and `cxx.lib`. Looking at the verbose output above, the option `-lmpi` should attempt to look for an `mpi.lib` (as per the 4th line in the excerpt).