# Why can't ld called from MSYS find (existing static) library when arguments are read from a response @file containing backslashes?

Tags: path, linker, static-libraries, ld, mingw-w64

This is basically the same issue as in [mingw ld cannot find some library which is exist in the search path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21596268/mingw-ld-cannot-find-some-library-which-is-exist-in-the-search-path), [MinGW linker can't find MPICH2 libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347424/mingw-linker-cant-find-mpich2-libraries) - and I'm aware that [there are heaps of posts on StackOverflow regarding the issue of static and dynamic linking with MinGW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30803765/linker-cannot-find-existing-static-library-file/30815765#30815765) - but I couldn't find anything that explains how I can troubleshoot.

I am building a project with a huge linker command like (via `g++`) on MinGW, in a MSYS2 shell (`git-bash.exe`). The process fails with, among others:

```
/z/path/to/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lssl
```

I add `-Wl,--verbose` to the `g++` linker call (to be passed to `ld`), and I can see for the `-L/z/path/to/libs/openssl/lib/mingw -lssl`:

```
...
attempt to open /z/path/to/libs/openssl/lib/mingw/libssl.a failed
...
/z/path/to/libs/openssl/lib/mingw/ssl.dll failed
attempt to open /z/path/to/libs/openssl/lib/mingw\libssl.a failed
...
```

But this is weird, because the file exists?

```
$ file /z/path/to/libs/openssl/lib/mingw/libssl.a
/z/path/to/libs/openssl/lib/mingw/libssl.a: current ar archive
```

(... and it was built with the same compiler on the same machine)?

Weirdly, once it attempts to open with forward slash `.../libssl.a`, once with backslash `...\libssl.a` - but at least the first path checks out in a `bash` shell, as shown above?

It gets even worse if I try to specify `-l:libssl.a` -- or if I specify `-L/z/path/to/libs/openssl/lib/mingw -Wl,-Bstatic -lssl` -- instead; then all attempts to open are with a backslash:

```
...
attempt to open /z/path/to/scripts/other/build/openssl/build/mingw/lib\libssl.a failed
attempt to open /z/path/to/libs/openssl/lib/mingw\libssl.a failed
...
```

To top it all off, if I look it up manually through the command line using `ld`, it is found ?!:

```
$ ld -L/z/path/to/libs/openssl/lib/mingw -lssl --verbose
attempt to open Z:/path/to/libs/openssl/lib/mingw/libssl.dll.a failed
attempt to open Z:/path/to/libs/openssl/lib/mingw/ssl.dll.a failed
attempt to open Z:/path/to/libs/openssl/lib/mingw/libssl.a succeeded
```

Does anyone have an idea why this happens, and how can I get `ld` to finally find these libraries? Or rather - how can I troubleshoot, and understand why these libraries are not found, when they exist at the paths where `ld` tries to open them?

---

OK, found something more - not sure if this is a bug; but my problem is that I'm actually reading arguments from a file (otherwise I get `g++: Argument list too long`). So, to simulate that:

```
$ echo " -Wl,--verbose -L/z/path/to/libs/openssl/lib/mingw -lssl -lcrypto " > tmcd3

$ g++ @tcmd3 2>&1 | grep succeeded | grep ssl                                   
# nothing

$ g++ `cat tcmd3` 2>&1 | grep succeeded | grep ssl
attempt to open Z:/path/to/libs/openssl/lib/mingw/libssl.a succeeded
attempt to open Z:/path/to/libs/openssl/lib/mingw/libcrypto.a succeeded
```

... it turns out, if the very same arguments are fed on the command line, then static library lookup succeeds - but if the arguments are read from file through the `@` at-sign, then static library lookup fails?! Unfortunately, I cannot use on my actual project, since even with `cat`, I'd still get `g++: Argument list too long` ... So how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MSYS has special handling of directories as arguments when they are used in the shell. This translates e.g. `/<drive_letter>/blabla` to the proper Windows style paths. This is to accomodate Unix programs that don't handle `Z:` style directory root.

What you see here is that MSYS isn't performing this interpretation for string read from a file. When you think about it, it's very logical, but as you have experienced first-hand, also sometimes annoying.

Long story short: don't put Unix style paths in files with command arguments. Instead, pass them through e.g. `cygpath -w`, which works in MSYS2 (which should be the MSYS that Git for Windows 2+ comes with).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, with some more experiments, I noticed that:

- `-L/z/path/to/libs/openssl/lib/mingw`, the Unix path specification, tends to fail - while if we specify the same, except starting with a Windows drive letter, that is:
- `-LZ:/path/to/libs/openssl/lib/mingw`, then things work - also from an arguments file with `@` at-sign:

```
$ echo " -Wl,--verbose -LZ:/path/to/libs/openssl/lib/mingw -lssl -lcrypto " > tmcd3
$ g++ @tcmd3 2>&1 | grep succeeded | grep ssl
attempt to open Z:/path/to/libs/openssl/lib/mingw/libssl.a succeeded
attempt to open Z:/path/to/libs/openssl/lib/mingw/libcrypto.a succeeded
```

I guess, since the shell is MSYS2/`git-bash.exe`, entering full POSIX paths on the shell with `/z/...` is not a problem, because the shell will convert them - but in a file, there is nothing to convert them, so we must use Windows/MingW convention to specify them...